# What strategies benefit from EURO (ECB) interest rate hike(s) long term?

Tags: interest-rates, hedging

I would like to know which strategies would perform well if the ECB hikes interest rates?

Alternatively, what is a good strategy to hedge a loan in EUR against interest rate hikes?

Comment: (1) You can only profit if the ECB raises rates more or less than other people expect, and *you* are right. Which way do you think it is going to go? (2) to hedge a loan you could be long Euribor futures, alternatively you could buy an Interest Rate Cap from an investment bank.